# Managing Azure Web Site Configutation

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-web-app-service

There are probably no less than 150 different configuration options for an instance/application of Azure App Service Web Apps. This is only part of the list and each of these items have various options and inputs.

- Authentication/Authorization
- Application insights
- Managed service identity
- Backups
- Networking settings
- Scaling settings
- WebJobs
- Push
- MySQL in App
- easy tables
- data connections
- API definitions
- CORS settings

... etc, etc

From a configuration management perspective, how do I either source control these settings (preferred) in a config file or use a configuration management tool to manage them?

I don't see a way to define the individual apps in an ARM template.

My goal is to have a consistent and repeatable application configuration across multiple applications and prevent mistakes with manual setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my understanding, the **settings** you mentioned includes the whole configurations of the web app, like Deployment slots, Backups, etc.

AFAIK, you may not be able to control them(at least like Deployment slots, Backups,etc) via the ways you mentioned.

> My goal is to have a consistent and repeatable application configuration across multiple applications and prevent mistakes with manual setup.

Currently, the closest way is to [clone web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning), you could use it via the portal or powershell, but it could not support clone the whole configurations in the web app even if you use it.

Also **note**: App cloning is currently only supported for premium tier app service plans.